# AttributeError- 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I keep getting this error message:

```
newmaxleft=cl1count.index(max(cl1count))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

The purpose of the code is to find the first occurrents of the column with the largest amount of white pixels.

My Code:

```
cl = cl[top:bottom, left:right]
            cl1mask = np.uint8(np.where(cl == 0, 0, 1))
            cl1count = cv2.reduce(cl1mask, 0, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32SC1)
            cl1count.flatten().tolist()
            newmaxleft=cl1count.index(max(cl1count))
```

Comment: `numpy.ndarray` is not the same as `pandas.Series`.

Comment: You want [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy doesn't have index method. It uses where (for general purposes) or some specific functions. In your case the best choice is

```
newmaxleft = cl1count.argmax()
```

You can also use

```
newmaxleft = np.where(a==max(a))[0][0]
```

But it's less efficient. First [0] returns np.array of positions, second [0] returns first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because numpy arrays don't have the index attribute, as the error says. So instead of using index, use something like `newmaxleft=np.where(cl1count == max(cl1count))` where you can use `newmaxleft[0]` to get the first occurrence. You could also use `argmax`.