# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'12

Tags: numpy-ndarray, attributeerror

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## Get the number of documents

n = len(documents)

## Get a list of the words in the vocabulary

vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()

## Create an empty list to store the inverse document frequencies

idf = []

## Iterate over the words in the vocabulary

for word in vocab:
# Count the number of documents in which the word appears
df = sum(count_matrix.toarray()[:, vocab.index(word)])
# Calculate the inverse document frequency
idf_i = np.log(1 + n/1 + df) + 1
# Append the inverse document frequency to the list
idf.append(idf_i)

## Convert the list to a NumPy array

idf = np.array(idf)

## Print the inverse document frequency vector

print(idf)

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[344], line 16
13 # Iterate over the words in the vocabulary
14 for word in vocab:
15     # Count the number of documents in which the word appears
---> 16     df = sum(count_matrix.toarray()[:, vocab.index(word)])
17     # Calculate the inverse document frequency
18     idf_i = np.log(1 + n/1 + df) + 1

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

i use import pandas as pd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError- 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930670/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-index)